# Upgrade a flutter project to use swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm adding a swift dependency to an existing flutter project. In a new project this isn't a problem, I'd just create the project with swift enabled:

```
flutter create -i swift my_project
```

With my existing project is there a way to ***upgrade*** it to use swift without having to re-create it and redo all of my manual iOS changes?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204418/make-flutter-project-swift-compatible-after-creation/54205563#54205563) but the accepted answer there can be summarized "recreate the project and re-make your manual project changes" which is exactly what I'm hoping not to have to do.

Comment: I had problems with the very same package but I realized that I didn't actually need it. In my case I could just pass mailto through url launcher and it would by open the default mailing app on the device (provided they've set one up on ios). This question has been answer before on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204418/make-flutter-project-swift-compatible-after-creation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make flutter project swift compatible AFTER creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204418/make-flutter-project-swift-compatible-after-creation)